# Javascript in lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I have a problem while using a JavaScript in lightbox: I have implemented a rating function to my site. When I use the functionality in the normal embedded html it works great but the user is taken to the feedback page. I wanted to use lightbox for the feedback to give the possibility to the user to give feedback and stay where he actually is.

The status quo: Everything works fine but the JS-script does not start in lightbox. Means that the radio buttons for the rating are not replaced by the script with the star images. Finally I receive this error:

> TypeError: starRating is undefined
>   starRating.create('.feedbackSelect');

and when I copy the error out of Firebug I receive this:

> TypeError: starRating is undefined
>   http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxxx/interface/themes/blueprint/js/jquery.min.js/eval/seq/2 Line 2

The var starRating is defined in the further lines:

```
var starRating = {
  create: function(selector) {
...
```

What confuses me is that Firebug is referring to another file, namely the jQuery library and again: without lightbox it works as it should. I'd be thankful for any hints how to solve this!

p.d.: Here is the smarty html code:

```
{js filename="feedback.js"}

{* <div class="span-5 {if $sidebarOnLeft}pull-18 sidebarOnLeft{else}last{/if}">
  {include file="MyResearch/menu.tpl"}
</div> *}

<div class="span-18{if $sidebarOnLeft} push-5 last{/if}">
  {if $user->cat_username}
    <h1>{translate text='Feedback'}</h1>
    <br>
    {if $success}
      <p class="success">{translate text='feedback_thanks'}</p>
    {else}
      {if $errorMsg}
        <p class="error">{translate text=$errorMsg}</p>
      {/if}
      <form method="post" action="{$url}/Feedback/Feedback" id="feedback_form">
        <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="{$hash|escape}" />
        <table id="feedback" class="citation">
        {if $feedbackIssues}

          {foreach from=$feedbackIssues item=issue}


        <tr>
          <th>{translate text=$issue->title}:</th>
          <td class="feedbackSelect">
            <label for="{$issue->title|lower|regex_replace:'/[^a-z0-9]/':''|escape}-1"><input id="{$issue->title|lower|regex_replace:'/[^a-z0-9]/':''|escape}-1" name="issue{$issue->id|escape}" type="radio" value="1"/>0.5</label>
            <label for="{$issue->title|lower|regex_replace:'/[^a-z0-9]/':''|escape}-2"><input id="{$issue->title|lower|regex_replace:'/[^a-z0-9]/':''|escape}-2" name="issue{$issue->id|escape}" type="radio" value="2"/>1</label>
            <label for="{$issue->title|lower|regex_replace:'/[^a-z0-9]/':''|escape}-3"><input id="{$issue->title|lower|regex_replace:'/[^a-z0-9]/':''|escape}-3" name="issue{$issue->id|escape}" type="radio" value="3"/>1.5</label>
            <label for="{$issue->title|lower|regex_replace:'/[^a-z0-9]/':''|escape}-4"><input id="{$issue->title|lower|regex_replace:'/[^a-z0-9]/':''|escape}-4" name="issue{$issue->id|escape}" type="radio" value="4"/>2</label>
            <label for="{$issue->title|lower|regex_replace:'/[^a-z0-9]/':''|escape}-5"><input id="{$issue->title|lower|regex_replace:'/[^a-z0-9]/':''|escape}-5" name="issue{$issue->id|escape}" type="radio" value="5"/>2.5</label>
            <label for="{$issue->title|lower|regex_replace:'/[^a-z0-9]/':''|escape}-6"><input id="{$issue->title|lower|regex_replace:'/[^a-z0-9]/':''|escape}-6" name="issue{$issue->id|escape}" type="radio" value="6"/>3</label>
            <label for="{$issue->title|lower|regex_replace:'/[^a-z0-9]/':''|escape}-7"><input id="{$issue->title|lower|regex_replace:'/[^a-z0-9]/':''|escape}-7" name="issue{$issue->id|escape}" type="radio" value="7"/>3.5</label>
            <label for="{$issue->title|lower|regex_replace:'/[^a-z0-9]/':''|escape}-8"><input id="{$issue->title|lower|regex_replace:'/[^a-z0-9]/':''|escape}-8" name="issue{$issue->id|escape}" type="radio" value="8"/>4</label>
            <label for="{$issue->title|lower|regex_replace:'/[^a-z0-9]/':''|escape}-9"><input id="{$issue->title|lower|regex_replace:'/[^a-z0-9]/':''|escape}-9" name="issue{$issue->id|escape}" type="radio" value="9"/>4.5</label> 
            <label for="{$issue->title|lower|regex_replace:'/[^a-z0-9]/':''|escape}-10"><input id="{$issue->title|lower|regex_replace:'/[^a-z0-9]/':''|escape}-10" name="issue{$issue->id|escape}" type="radio" value="10"/>5</label>  
          </td>
        </tr>
        {/foreach}
        {/if}

        <tr>
          <th>{translate text="Comments"}:</th>
          <td><textarea name="comment" class="formularLarge">{$comment}</textarea></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
          <td><input type="submit" name="submitFeedback" value="{translate text="submit_feedback"}" class="senden"></td>
        </tr>

        </table>
      </form>
    {/if}
  {else}
    {include file="AJAX/login.tpl"}
  {/if}
</div>


<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: need more of your code to help you.. may be the html part... is your lightbox html part is generated dynamically

Comment: ok, I've added it to the question.